# Replace objects with correct rotaion

Tags: objects

I have a shoe file with stitches. The default stitches in the obj file have high polygon count and thereby increasing my file size by alot. I have made a simpler stitch that i want to replace all the existing ones with.

The problem however is that every stitch had the same origion.
Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C > 'Origin to Geometry' aligns the origin but does not help with the rotation.
I am using 'link object data' (Ctrl+L) for replace. >

Initial stitches>
[image: initial stitches]
Final result>
[image: Final result]

Comment: Try rotating your smaller stitch object 90 degrees on which ever axis is out, then apply rotation.  (same operation would be selecting all verts in edit mode and rotate about origin).  Re link  mesh and check alignment. If they're up, choose app. axis next time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Its not clear. I want some way to not have to rotate every single stitch, instead to apply an action that aligns all.